# Logical operations on CSV with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, logical-operators

I need to apply some changes in Col01 based on the value in Col03

```
Col01,Col02,Col03
empty,empty,6
empty,empty,19
empty,empty,75
empty,empty,87
empty,red,145
empty,empty,625
empty,empty,abc
```

Make the content in Col01 be:

- 'small' if Col03 value is less or equal than 50
- 'medium' if Col03 value is in between 51 and 100
- 'large' if Col03 value is in between 51 and 100
- 'text' if Col03 value is a text (not a number)

Result:

```
Col01,Col02,Col03
small,empty,6
small,empty,19
medium,empty,75
medium,empty,87
large,empty,145
large,empty,625
text,empty,abc
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can Col03 only be integers or text? Medium and large have the same requirements..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this correct? There are multiple ways to achieve this. Ex:

```
#Sample data
$csv = @"
Col01,Col02,Col03
empty,empty,6
empty,empty,19
empty,empty,75
empty,empty,87
empty,red,145
empty,empty,625
empty,empty,abc
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

#Uncomment to read from file
#$csv = Import-CSV -Path C:\MyFile.csv

$csv | ForEach-Object {

    #Get current Col03 value
    $col3 = $_.Col03.Trim()

    #Calculate new Col01 value 
    $val = if($col3 -match '^\d+$') {
        #Col03 is integer
        if([int]$col3 -le 50) { "small" }
        elseif ([int]$col3 -le 100) { "medium" }
        else { "large" }
    } else { "text" }

    #Replace Col01-value
    $_.Col01 = $val

    #Output modified object
    $_
}
```

Or using a switch. This sample also saves the result to a file:

```
$csv = @"
Col01,Col02,Col03
empty,empty,6
empty,empty,19
empty,empty,75
empty,empty,87
empty,red,145
empty,empty,625
empty,empty,abc
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

#Uncomment to read from file
#$csv = Import-CSV -Path C:\MyFile.csv

$csv | ForEach-Object {

    $_.Col01 = switch($_.Col03.Trim()) {
        #Contains non-digit - text
        {$_ -match '\D'} { 'text'; break; }
        #Number - pick category
        {[int]$_ -le 50} { 'small'; break; }
        {[int]$_ -le 100} { 'medium'; break; }
        {[int]$_ -gt 100} { 'large'; break; } 
    }  

    #Output modified object
    $_
} | Export-CSV -Path MyOuput.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
Col01  Col02 Col03
-----  ----- -----
small  empty 6    
small  empty 19   
medium empty 75   
medium empty 87   
large  red   145  
large  empty 625  
text   empty abc
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't output the file. I'm a noob :)

$csv = Import-CSV -Path C:\marketing\sandbox\MyFile.csv
$csv | ForEach-Object {

    #Get current Col03 value
    $col3 = $_.Col03.Trim()
    #Calculate new Col01 value 
    $val = if($col3 -match '^\d+$') {
        #Col03 is integer
        if([int]$col3 -le 50) { "small" }
        elseif ([int]$col3 -le 100) { "medium" }
        else { "large" }
    } else { "text" }

    #Replace Col01-value
    $_.Col01 = $val

    $_
    
    Out-File -Encoding "utf8" -Path "C:\marketing\sandbox\out.csv"
}

Comment: Add `| Export-CSV -Path MyOuput.csv -NoTypeInformation` to the last line in my answer

Comment: a cmd kind window opened up


C:\marketing\sandbox>PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File rules.ps1


cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:

Comment: Looks like you didn't add it to the last line (after `}`), but rather on it own line below. See alternative solution, it includes exporting

Comment: The switch version worked better but for some reason the medium, between 50 and 100 didn't work. Everything under 100 was labeled small

Answer (score 0):

It's perfect practice fodder, you can write it in several ways, the core of it is:

- Reading the CSV lines

  - You can do it as lines of text, but the 'right' way in PowerShell is `Import-Csv`).
- Testing the text/number part

  1. handle the text condition first (in your code) and anything getting past that *will be* numbers.
  2. try and handle the number cases first, anything getting past that *will be* text.
  3. Assume it's all numbers, if it breaks, it's text. This is workable, but it's using Exceptions for control flow, and that's bad. It's bad because Exceptions are for exceptional conditions and you're expecting text as a normal part of the program operation, and it's kinda bad because Exceptions have lots of overhead. However, you are the programmer and you can make the choice to use them if you want - e.g. it's particularly readable/clear.
- Export the CSV lines

  - Again you can do it as lines of text, but `Export-Csv` is there to be paired with `Import-Csv`, so that's the 'right' way in PowerShell.

And in PowerShell terms it makes sense that you arrange it:

```
Import-Csv | ForEach-Object { process one CSV row at a time } | Export-Csv

(as opposed to:
$foo = import-csv
$bar = @()
foreach ($line in $foo) {
   #...
   $bar += $line
}
which is workable but ugly and wasteful of memory and CPU and won't scale nicely)
```

OK, so we've dealt with the structure of the read/process/write part. Now you're assigning the number values to buckets.

```
0-10    11-20    21-30    31-40
\__/    \___/    \___/    \___/
```

or whatever size ranges / bucket conditions.

and that pattern screams `if/else` or `switch`.

So the remaining part is, which one of the 1. 2. 3. approaches do you choose, where and how do you split the text from the numbers, and how do you assign the numbers into buckets.

Most of this choice is about readability and your preference.

Buckets with a start and end imply a double test like `start -le $num -and $num -lt end` and then the two edge cases just have a single test. But your three buckets mean one needs a double test and two need a single test.

```
if ($foo -gt 100)
elseif (51 -lt $foo -and $foo -le 100)
elseif ($foo -lt 50)
```

Look at that mishmash of if/elseif and single/double tests. But because your buckets hit up against each other nicely, you can make use / misuse of fall-through testing to have:

```
if ($foo -gt 100) { big    }
if ($foo -le 100) { medium }
if ($foo -le 50 ) { small  }
```

OK, some will get assigned 'medium' and then 'small', but this layout is a lot nicer to read, to see what it's doing, isn't it?

And the fallthrough implicitly happens in a `switch` unless you stop it, so that will have switch cases with or without a `break` to stop the fallthrough.

If you choose to match the *text* first, you're probably going to use regexes to identify things which aren't numbers (backwardsly), so I get this:

```
Import-Csv .\t.csv | ForEach-Object { 

    if ($_.Col03 -notmatch '^\d+$')
    {
        $_.Col01 = 'text'
    }
    else 
    {
        if ([int]$_.Col03 -gt 100) { $_.Col01 = 'large'  }
        if ([int]$_.Col03 -le 100) { $_.Col01 = 'medium' }
        if ([int]$_.Col03 -le 50)  { $_.Col01 = 'small'  }
    }

    $_

} # | Export-Csv out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Which is workable, but eh. If you choose to identify the numbers first, you can either use the same regex pattern, or tell the .Net framework to `TryParse`-ing the text as a number. I get:

```
Import-Csv .\t.csv | ForEach-Object { 

    [int]$n = 0

    if ([int]::TryParse($_.Col03, [ref]$n)) 
    {
        if ($n -gt 100) { $_.Col01 = 'large'  }
        if ($n -le 100) { $_.Col01 = 'medium' }    
        if ($n -le 50)  { $_.Col01 = 'small'  }
    }
    else 
    {
        $_.Col01 = 'text'
    }

    $_

} # | Export-Csv out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Which isn't very pretty. Go for a regex / switch fallthrough combo and I get:

```
Import-Csv .\t.csv | ForEach-Object { 

    switch -regex ($_)
    {
        {$_.Col03 -notmatch '^\d+$'} { $_.Col01 = 'text'   ; break }
        {[int]$_.Col03 -gt 100}      { $_.Col01 = 'large'          }
        {[int]$_.Col03 -le 100}      { $_.Col01 = 'medium'         }
        {[int]$_.Col03 -le 50 }      { $_.Col01 = 'small'          }
    }

    $_
} # | Export-Csv out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Which is quite pretty, but the partial `; break` / fallthrough is just waiting for someone to make mistakes with reading it. And using Exception handling as control flow, I get this, (which I've changed to read the entire file into memory first because of scoping issues with `$_` inside the catch block):

```
$Rows = foreach ($Row in Import-Csv .\t.csv)
{ 
    try {
        if ([int]$Row.Col03 -gt 100) { $Row.Col01 = 'large'  }
        if ([int]$Row.Col03 -le 100) { $Row.Col01 = 'medium' }
        if ([int]$Row.Col03 -le 50)  { $Row.Col01 = 'small'  }
    } catch {
        $row.Col01 = 'text'
    }

    $row
}

$Rows # | Export-Csv out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

But they're all doing basically the same thing, and I can't think of a nicer way to do the bucketing, so all my answers are pretty much the same shape even if they do run through completely different code.

Frode F's use of PowerShell assigning from an `if` works in a different way again, but in that approach I can't use the fallthrough bucket check - hence his use of if/elseif/if instead of if/if/if. Which is kinda nice, and could be formatted as:

```
$row.Col01 =     if (                $n -le  50) { 'small'  }
             elseif ( 51 -lt $n -and $n -le 100) { 'medium' }
             elseif (100 -lt $n                ) { 'large'  }
```

and then it's clearer they are start/end ranges, and actually yeah I like Frode's approach best, just not formatted how he's formatted it, and wish I'd read his answer before writing this.

Comment: Good (and long!) explanation :-). Didn't spend much time making my code look good this time, because all the if's were ugly anyways...